# Can't concat bytes to str (Converting to Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert my Python 2 code to Python3 but I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "markovtest.py", line 73, in <module>
    get_all_tweets("quit_cryan")
  File "markovtest.py", line 41, in get_all_tweets
    outtweets = [(tweet.text.encode("utf-8") + str(b" ")) for tweet in alltweets]
  File "markovtest.py", line 41, in <listcomp>
    outtweets = [(tweet.text.encode("utf-8") + str(b" ")) for tweet in alltweets]
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

The problem is in this for loop:

```
outtweets = [(tweet.text.encode("utf-8") + " ") for tweet in alltweets]
```

I have tried changing encode to decode or removing the encode parameter altogether but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running 2to3 on your code or something, because the code in the traceback doesn't match the source code you've shown.

Answer (score 8):

Python3 has several different 'string' types. Details on which ones there are and what they are supposed to do can be found [here](https://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html).

You are trying to combine a bytes string (basically an immutable character array) to a unicode string. This can not (easily) be done.

The problem in your code snippet is that the tweet text, most likely a string, is converted to bytes with the `encode` method. This works fine, but when you try to concatenate the space `" "` (which is a string) to the bytes object the error occurs. You can either remove the `encode` and do the concatenation as strings (and maybe encode later) or make the space a bytes object by adding a 'b' before the quotes like this `b" "`.

Let's take a look at your options:

```
In [1]: type("foo")
Out[1]: str

In [2]: type("foo".encode("utf-8"))
Out[2]: bytes

In [3]: "foo" + " "  # str + str
Out[3]: 'foo '

In [4]: "foo".encode("utf-8") + " "  # str + bytes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5c7b745d9739> in <module>()
----> 1 "foo".encode("utf-8") + " "

TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

I guess for you problem, the simplest solution would be to make the space a byte string (as below). I hope this helps.

```
In [5]: "foo".encode("utf-8") + b" "  # bytes + bytes
Out[5]: b'foo '
```